# MS SQL Server cursor output with huge amount of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

When I execute the following the cursor I created, the end result is fine. Altough when running the script i get a huge amount of results (160 million) in my query output screen for every record he needs to update i see a list. Can someone have a look?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE
      @Lidmaatschap_external_id VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @DATE DATETIME

SET @DATE = GETDATE()

DECLARE remco_cursor CURSOR FOR
     SELECT lm.crmp_externalmemberid
     FROM Contact AS c
     INNER JOIN crmp_lidmaatschap AS lm ON c.ContactId = lm.crmp_contactid
     WHERE @date BETWEEN lm.crmp_startdate AND ISNULL(lm.crmp_Einddatum, '2099-12-12')

OPEN remco_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM remco_cursor
INTO @Lidmaatschap_external_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN

     SELECT @Lidmaatschap_external_id
     FROM Contact AS c
     INNER JOIN crmp_lidmaatschap AS lm ON c.ContactId = lm.crmp_contactid
     WHERE @date BETWEEN crmp_startdate AND ISNULL(crmp_Einddatum, '2099-12-12')

     UPDATE Contact
     SET crmp_externalmemberidfp = @Lidmaatschap_external_id
     WHERE CURRENT OF remco_cursor

     FETCH NEXT FROM remco_cursor
     INTO @Lidmaatschap_external_id

END

CLOSE remco_cursor
DEALLOCATE remco_cursor

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

This is my first post, sorry for the messed up post layout.

Comment: It's not clear why you have (essentially) the same `SELECT` statement inside your loop as the one that defines your cursor. What were you trying to do there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, without using any cursors -

```
UPDATE c
SET crmp_externalmemberidfp = lm.crmp_externalmemberid
FROM dbo.Contact c
JOIN dbo.crmp_lidmaatschap lm ON c.ContactId = lm.crmp_contactid
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN lm.crmp_startdate AND ISNULL(lm.crmp_Einddatum, '20991212')
```

Also try to use `PRINT` -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Lidmaatschap_external_id VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE remco_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
     SELECT lm.crmp_externalmemberid
     FROM dbo.Contact c
     JOIN dbo.crmp_lidmaatschap lm ON c.ContactId = lm.crmp_contactid
     WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN lm.crmp_startdate AND ISNULL(lm.crmp_Einddatum, '20991212')

OPEN remco_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM remco_cursor INTO @Lidmaatschap_external_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

     PRINT @Lidmaatschap_external_id

     UPDATE dbo.Contact
     SET crmp_externalmemberidfp = @Lidmaatschap_external_id
     WHERE CURRENT OF remco_cursor

     FETCH NEXT FROM remco_cursor INTO @Lidmaatschap_external_id

END

CLOSE remco_cursor
DEALLOCATE remco_cursor
```